# Execute slideup and slidedown automatically when any div is showing or hidding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to apply jquery slideup/slidedown method automatically if any div is hide/show inside the body tag in any time.

```
$(window).load(function(){
$("*").show(function(){
   $(this).slideDown(2000);
});
$("*").hide(function(){});
  $(this).slideUp(2000);
});
```

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-trigger-custom-event-show-hide-element/

Comment: First please edit your code snippet - you will see that slide up executes outside of the hide handler.

Secondly you are missusing show/hide - see API docs http://api.jquery.com/show/ - you probably meant `on('show', function () { ... })`

Thirdly @Learner comment may be of help.